# Merge multiple .MOBI files into one

Tags: mobile, kindle

Downloaded a book in the .mobi file format.  The files came separated by chapters.  Hoping to find an application or a way to merge all the .mobi files into one single file.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ebook conversion.

Comment: Someone should migrate this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing the following steps

1. Use [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to convert all mobi to epub
2. Download [LRF-EPUB-TOOLS](http://code.google.com/p/lrf-epub-tools/) to merge the epub books
3. (Optional) - Use [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/) to then fix the book (make sure chapters in right order, etc)
4. Use calibre to convert the new epub back to mobi

This seems like a lot of steps but it produces a single mobi.

Comment: A much simpler alternative to LRF-EPUB-TOOLS is [Epub Merge](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=169744). It's a Calibre plugin, so it's easier to use and can be installed from inside calibre. It ONLY merges epubs though.

Answer (score 1):

[Try converting like this.](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=94064)